# Save ElasticSearch snapshot physical files in specific location

Tags: elasticsearch

To take a snap shot for ElasticSearch, we will need to first set up the snapshot repository:

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/repo_companyA' -d '{ 
    "type" : "fs", 
    "settings": {
        "location": "/data/backup/companyA", 
        "compress":true
    }
}'
```

If my ElasticSearch is running on a G: hard drive, then the physical snapshot would be stored inside G: drive folder of where the ElasticSearch is running on.

What if I want my snapshot to be saved into F: drive instead?

Is it possible to set the repository to save the copy of snapshot into a different, specific physical location?

Comment: Have you tried setting an absolute location like `"F://data/backup/companyA"` ?

Comment: If this is Windows, the correct location path should be `F:\\data\\backup\\companyA`.

Comment: Doh! of course ;-) Good call @AndreiStefan

Comment: @Val I should have tried this earlier, many thanks :)